# SqlMembershipProvider With Aspnet_regsql.exe And Web.Config Configurations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, sqlmembershipprovider

I use `System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider` and `Aspnet_regsql.exe`. I installed the tables from `Aspnet_regsql.exe` into database with name `UserAuthentication` but when I run this code nothing goes to `Aspnet_regsql.exe` tables in database `UserAuthentication`. Where is the mistake here what else am I misssing ?

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Submit(User user)
        {
            SqlMembershipProvider provider = new SqlMembershipProvider();
            MembershipCreateStatus status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;


            provider.CreateUser(user.Username, user.Password, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, true, null, out status);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
```

ConnectionString:

```
<add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="Data
    Source=DOTNET-DEV9;Initial Catalog=UserAuthentication;Integrated
    Security=SSPI;" />
```

SqlProvider:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login/Index" 
        name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <!--<deny users="?" />-->
    </authorization>
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add
          name="SqlProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
          connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
          applicationName="MyApplication"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
          requiresUniqueEmail="true"
          passwordFormat="Hashed" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.CreateUser(username, password, String.Empty);
```

Comment: Now it throws exception "The password-answer supplied is invalid."

Comment: change requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" to false (as well as requiresUniqueEmail="true", set it to false) in your web.config